# STM32 external interrupt responds only in debug mode

Tags: c, debugging, microcontroller, interrupt, stm32

I have a problem with my STM32F103C8T6 microcontroller. I am using (as an exercise) external interrupts to toggle on/off a led, by pressing an external switch wich in turn is connected to PC13. I am using StdPeriph Library.

When the chip has programmed, nothing happens. On the contrary, when I am using the debugger (debug in Coocox), the chip is working fine. I can not figure out where is the problem.

Can you help me please?
Here is my code.

```
#include<stm32f10x.h>
#include<stm32f10x_rcc.h>
#include<stm32f10x_gpio.h>

#include<stm32f10x_exti.h>
#include<misc.h>

typedef enum{
    on,
    off
}state;
state led=on;

int main(void){

    // enable clocks
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOC,ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB,ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_AFIO,ENABLE);

    // uncomment to disable/remap JTAG pins
    GPIO_PinRemapConfig(GPIO_Remap_SWJ_NoJTRST,ENABLE);
    GPIO_PinRemapConfig(GPIO_Remap_SWJ_JTAGDisable,ENABLE);

    // configure PC13 as input
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_13;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC,&GPIO_InitStructure);

    // configure PB8 as led output
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_8;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB,&GPIO_InitStructure);

    // connect PC13 to EXTI controller
    GPIO_EXTILineConfig(GPIO_PortSourceGPIOC,GPIO_PinSource13);

    // enable and configure EXTI controller
    EXTI_InitTypeDef EXTI_InitStructure;
    EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Line=EXTI_Line13;
    EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Mode=EXTI_Mode_Interrupt;
    EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Trigger=EXTI_Trigger_Falling;
    EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_LineCmd=ENABLE;
    EXTI_Init(&EXTI_InitStructure);

    // enable IRQ
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn);
    NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping(NVIC_PriorityGroup_2);

    // Configure NVIC
    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel=EXTI15_10_IRQn;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd=ENABLE;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority=2;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority=2;
    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

    // switch on led
    GPIO_WriteBit(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_8,Bit_SET);

    while(1);

    return 0;
}

void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void){

    // clear pending bit
    if(EXTI_GetITStatus(EXTI_Line13)!=RESET){
        EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_Line13);
    }

    if(led==off){
        GPIO_WriteBit(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_8,Bit_SET);
        led=on;
    }else{
        GPIO_WriteBit(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_8,Bit_RESET);
        led=off;
    }
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT
void assert_failed(uint8_t * file,uint32_t line){
    /* Infinite loop */
    while (1);
}
#endif
```

Comment: working when you debug it often means uninitialized variables.

Comment: Thank you Jean-François Fabre for your answer. I think that everything is initialized.

Comment: Do you reset after programming?
Where is the code running? Flash or RAM?
Is there a breakpoint staying somewhere?

Comment: I haven't used Coocox, but can you make sure that your build and debug settings are not targeting different things or have different settings?

Comment: Yes I always put the reset button. The code runs from flash. All breakpoints have been cleared

Comment: Yes Cody G. I have checked all these settings.

Comment: Did you pull BOOT0 pin low ?

Comment: Yes, BOOT0 is fine. If I discard the interrupt and poll the PC13, then the chip works fine. I think that the problem is in software, not in hardware.

Comment: maybe this link could help forward: https://github.com/blahlt/notes/wiki/STM32F103C8T6-(4.-Pertrauktys-(angl.-interrupts))

Comment: caveat: I'm not very familiar with the indicated chip family.  However, I do not see where the code is enabling the peripheral clock and I do not see where the code is enabling the 'master' interrupt enable bit.  The debugger will do all that, but the standalone code must do that also, so the code operates correctly when the debugger is not attached.  I also do not see where the 'watchdog' is being initialized nor where the 'watchdog is being either disabled or 'kicked' on a regular basis.

Comment: Make sure that you have your interrupt vector in the right place (VECT_TAB_OFFSET).

Comment: @staringlizard: Do you mean the startup file?

Comment: @jojosthegreat: when using cmsis there is a file called system_stm32f7xx.c (for f7 series). Here you can put an offset for your interrupt vector depending where you are flashing your software. The constant in this case and file is named VECT_TAB_OFFSET. In any case, surely a part of your code will place the interrupt vectors somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well. I'm using a STM32F030.
The problem for me was not having the SYSCFG clock enabled, which is bit 0 of RCC APB2ENR register. I'm guessing this setting is enabled in debug, so that the software can debug? Otherwise the clock is disabled!

I finally found this by looking into the STM32F1 reference manual, which is slightly more comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks. My problem was very similar on a STM32L073 chip: I was using the LL_EXTI_LINEXX instead of LL_SYSCFG_EXTI_LINEXX to set up the EXTI Source and this cause the issue where I couldn't reset the interrupt. Your answer pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have knowledge about the mentioned controller, but I worked on STM32L4 series controllers. In STM32L4  push button is connected to the PC13 pin. I observed gpio debouncing when pressing the push button. In your EXTI15_10_IRQHandler() implement debouncing logic. Make sure the interrupt is reaching this function for only once per button press. May be the debugger is slowing down the processor(cpu running in lower frequency compared to free run) and you are getting the interrupts properly.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use external interrupts for the buttons or keys. It should be done in the timer interrupt.

Comment: I didn't think it is always good to use timer interrupt (ie; POLLING) in your code. It will be depends on for what application you are implementing the firmware. For example If you have a lot of peripheral devices and you are read/writing lot of data in those devices it is bad idea to use times based interrupt on an single threaded system like the STM32 with bare metal programming. It is better to use the external interrupt, pause the operation, handle the interrupt, resume the operation than waiting for seconds to finish the operation. Hardware interrupts are invented to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a very bad idea to use external interrupts for the buttons and keys. You should use the timer interrupt instead.

You can see simple implementation of the key in the timer interrupt (click, double click, long click events supported) here : https://www.diymat.co.uk/arm-three-function-click-double-and-long-click-button-library-timer-interrupt-driven/

Comment: I didn't think it is always good to use timer interrupt (ie; POLLING) in your code. It will be depends on for what application you are implementing the firmware. For example If you have a lot of peripheral devices and you are read/writing lot of data in those devices it is bad idea to use times based interrupt on an single threaded system like the STM32 with bare metal programming. It is better to use the external interrupt, pause the operation, handle the interrupt, resume the operation than waiting for seconds to finish the operation. Hardware interrupts are invented to solve this problem.

Comment: @NithinP do you know what polling is? It is the rhetoric question as you do not know at all. So please do not comment before you get some knowledge and experience. And the rest of your comment has the same quality as the beginning.

Comment: @ PeterJ_01 Since you feel I don't know what is polling can you please point to your definition of polling? You can see my definition of polling in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)

Comment: @NithinP you cite something you do not understand. Not blocking interrupt approach is not polling. EXTI interrupts are not good for the keys and buttons -- why? it was explained even on this site 1000s of times. Get some experience and then comment.

Answer (score -1):

Do you use different build config for debug? If so, try making the `led` variable `volatile` and see if it helps.
If not: add some delay loop, i.e. `voliatile unsigned i; for (i=0; i < 50000u; ++i);` after clearing the EXTI bit in the ISR. This is generally a bad pratcice to use blocking delays in the interrupt service (if it's ever a good practice...) but might be helpful to see if it is related to debuncing not done properly. If it helps, then debouncing the switch is the most likely problem.

EDIT: consider using bit-banding (if possible) to access the output port, then you could do sth like `bind_band_led_port ^= 1;`, but that's just a side note.

Comment: bitbandind is not present in the modern cores - M7 for example. Delays in the ISRs - this is just wrong and horrible advise. Do not use external interrupts for the bouncing stuff like buttons.

Comment: PeterJ_01 as you could see in my answer, I know it actually is a bad idea. But for diagnostic purposes it might be done and then removed when the problem is confirmed. I.e. it is a mispractice, but a completely well defined and predictable one.But in general  I agree, external interrupts should not be used for keyboard, unless debouncing is handled in hardware (sometimes it is)